# View [admin.sellers.show] not foun | Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php | line 137

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

I deploy laravel 5.8 project on server, then when I was tryng to make delete request got this error
the project work fine on the local

this error show on another pages when it tring to make request delete request ,

> View [admin.contacts.show] not found.

> View [admin.brands.show] not found

php version : v7.4.33

I run this commands in server terminal

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

it **still** show the same  **error**

note : I tried to deploy the same project on **another server** , I got the **same error** but it **fixed** with the previes command.
so did I miss something in the first  server ?

Comment: Do you have `/resources/views/admin/contacts/show.blade.php` and `/resouces/views/admin/brands/show.blade.php`?

Comment: @aynber no I don't have this pages

Comment: Then you need to either create those pages, or find out what is trying to include them and why. Since it happens on a DELETE, follow the request to see where it might be triggering.

Comment: I made a file named  `show.blade.php` in the seller's folder and just include echo 'hi', then I made a delete request I got 401 with a 'hi ' message, why is that happening??!  , I will post some code the delete request goes through

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer for my question , It's not one issue but 2 issues

first one is caching views , routes , and config
make sure to run this commands after each edit on the server.

```
php artisan view:cache 
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

---

then for some reason my server **delete request** was **not working**
why I don't know, because of that the project was **working fine locally** and fine on **another server** .. after tens times of edits and tests with no real results because of app caching I didn't not that after a long time of trying and testing, and debugging.
I realized that in my server **delete request** is called the **show** method which is like **destroy** method URL `https://url/sellers/{id}` but with the get method, so, and show method has this unknown view.

in the end, I used the cache command after each time I made an edit on the server and changed the **delete request** to **post request** with pass `_method: 'delete'` as body request and it's fixed.

**note**: delete request may work on another server because it's works on my second server

---

my test :

**delete request** only

[image]

response

[image]

---

**delete request** with `_method:'delete'`

[image]

request body

[image]

response

[image]

---

finaly with **post request** and `_method: 'delete'`

[image]

request body

[image]

response

[image]

done